# session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) return 0 items

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I'm adding a drag and drop support to my iPad app and all the functions for the UIDropInteractionDelegate are being called correctly but I'm getting 0 items for my session items:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    // Consume drag items (in this example, of type UIImage).
    session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) { imageItems in
        let images = imageItems as! [UIImage] // images.count is 0
        /*
         If you do not employ the loadObjects(ofClass:completion:) convenience
         method of the UIDropSession class, which automatically employs
         the main thread, explicitly dispatch UI work to the main thread.
         For example, you can use `DispatchQueue.main.async` method.
         */
        self.logo.image = images.first
        self.saveImageFile(data: images.first?.pngData(), withName: COMPANY_LOGO)
    }
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypeImage as String]) && session.items.count == 1
}
```

I'm dragging an image from my Photos app to my drop target.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you already implement this function? `func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool`  If so, what does it look like for you?

Comment: I've added the implementation.
It's returning true.

Comment: Try changing it to `return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)` and see what happens

Comment: Also what does `session.items.count` print out before you try to `loadObjects`?

Comment: session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) returns false and now the other functions aren't being called at all

Comment: This documentation seems to be similar to what you are trying to do https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_custom_view